# What is an antonym of a "wrapper function"?

Tags: terminology, wrapper

What is an antonym of a "wrapper function"?
Is there a term to reference the function that actually does most of the work?

I ran into this as I was writing comments. 
There's a function doXYZ(), doXYZ2() exposed to the users, but these functions are actually just wrappers and the real work is done in actually_doXYZ() for both of them, hidden from the users.
And I want to write in comments for actually_doXYZ() "This is ???? function for doXYZ()".

Does "Delegated function" make any sense?

Comment: "implementation function" works well for me.

Comment: How about just 'a worker function'?

Comment: If the name of the internal implementation function is good, you will not need to write that comment! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think is delegation. In OOP a wrapper is often used to decorate an object. When you think of a pizza you can decorate it with other tops and prize. Then you can run the outmost wrapper of the object to pass the object to the other wrappers and to sum the prize for the whole pizza.